# How do embed codes work?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking into how embed codes work but couldn't find any resources or tutorials. However know that some use a JavaScript file. However how does that work? Is the JavaScript responsible for loading the HTML?

Comment: And what exactly are "embed codes" ?

Comment: Embed codes are codes that allow you embed external elements.

Comment: Does the tag description really describe what you're talking about? If not, remove the tag.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about? Could it be the [embed tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) ?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm talking about. I've removed the tag if its confusing. There isn't a specific place describing the overall concept and how it should be done for different types of things.

Comment: The MDN link is not very helpful, but I guess that is because it's pretty straight forward, you add the embed tag with whatever content you'd like to embed ?

Comment: I guess you can probably embed a webpage but isn't it better if you somehow include a javascript file. Also aren't there multiple ways you can embed such as embed and some other ones which I think aren't used anymore for security reasons.

Comment: Your mixing terms which embed are you talking about. Provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

The point of the embed tag is that you don't need to worry about using javascript or anything to load the content that's being embedded, because it's being handled by the browser itself.

If you want to read about the specific standards that are used by the browsers to render the embed tag, the technical specifications are available from the W3C: [Html5 Embedded Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-embed-element).

That said, unless you're trying to build something like a new type of content that's going to be used via embeds or something, there's really no reason you need to worry about what's going on behind the scenes. You just give it your content and it does the heavy lifting for you!